# JSP/JSTL is not working

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am trying to implement a JSP application and I need help please.  There are two problems:

1) JSTL tags are not converted into HTML.

2) If I use plain java instead of JSTL inside JSP page, it still does not work.

I am using netbeans 7.3 with tomcat 7 as well as Java EE 6. I added to the project the JSTL library which comes with netbeans 7.3 (namely JSTL 1.1).

My web.xml starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
...
</web-app>
```

Here is an example code:

```
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private String name;
// setters and getters follow
}


public class Controller {
    public List<Item> getAllItems() {
        // returns a list of items (size of list = 2)
    }
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% 
           Controller controller = new Controller(); 
           List<Item> items = controller.getAllItems();
        %>
        <table>
        <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
            <tr>
                <td>${item.id}</td>
                <td>${item.name}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
</table>
    </body>
</html>
```

1)  The jstl code is not converted to html.  The source of the page looks like this:

```
...
<table>
<c:forEach items="" var="item">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
  </c:forEach> 
</table>
...
```

I have also tried to use ${item.getId()} and ${item.getName()} but same results

2)  If I substitute the c:forEach with java as following:

```
    <% for (Item item : items) {%>
        <tr>
            <td><%item.getId();%></td>
            <td><%item.getName();%></td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
```

I get the following source (recall that the size of List is 2):

```
    ...
        <tr>
            <td></td> 
            <td></td>  
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>    
        </tr>
```

What am I doing wrong? Have I setup jstl properly?  Notice that Controller is a plain java class, not a bean.  Do I need to make it a bean? If yes, how?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The symptoms indicate that JSTL isn't present in the webapp's runtime classpath at all. I don't do Netbeans, so I have no idea how to get it to do its job right, but you can verify this by letting it export the project as a WAR file and then extracting it using a ZIP tool and then checking if the JSTL JAR(s) are present in the `/WEB-INF/lib`. If it's not, then you've there the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Also, the JSP EL can't access local variables defined by scriptlets in the JSP. It only accesses page, request, session or application attributes. The controller should be a servlet, called before your JSP. Not created and invoked by your JSP.

Comment: @BalusC I extracted the .war file.  Both jstl.jar and standard.jar are contained in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: @JBNizet Can you give me more details as to how to do that?

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/1012/developing_mvc_applications/adf_aboutmvc2.html. Basically, the request goes to a servlet. The servlet stores Java beans in request attributes, and then use the request dispatcher to forward to a JSP. The JSP displays the data stored in the request attributes. This is the basic architecture behind all MVC frameworks, like Spring MVC, Stripes, Struts, etc.

Comment: Okay. And what when you manually deploy that WAR to a standalone Tomcat, without using Netbeans (and having it shutdown)?

Comment: Thanks both of you for your time and help.  I have changed the architecture of my application to use servlets instead and set the attributes accordingly.  Also I have abandoned the use of c:forEach.  Now everything works and I am more than happy.  Best wishes :)

Answer (score -1):

Check the version of the xsd used in your web.xml. In my case the version needed to be 2.5 and the older ones did not display the values in jsp. and no error was thrown.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```